# fabricjs can't load video by using canvas.loadFromJSON

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

```
var jsonData = {
   "objects" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "image",
            "left" : 167,
            "top" : 97,
            "width" : 480,
            "height" : 240,
            "id" : "DIN8DIF1",
            "userId" : "ITNTMB1B",
            "userName" : "Developer 1",
            "createTime" : "2016-01-08 14:45:28",
            "lastModify" : "2016-01-08 14:45:28",
            "src" : "data:video/mp4;base64,//data url
            "filters" : [],
            "crossOrigin" : ""
        }, 

    ],
    "background" : "#ffffff",
    "width" : 750,
    "height" : 530
}
canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonData);
```

this is the chrome console information

‘**Error loading data:video/mp4;base64,dataurl**’

How could I load video by using canvas.loadFromJSON?

Comment: Please add some code you have tried.

Comment: You are loading an image object but giving a video data? I'm not sure but that seems quite legit nothing is shown.

Comment: fabricjs can render videos with its image class, the problem is that when you load it back from json the video is no expected. Would you be so kind to provide a working fiddle on which i can see the matter?

Answer (score 1):

Lame I don't use stackoverflow enough to comment instead of answer but none-the-less. When originally loading the Video through the Image class you need to call..

```
fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
  canvas.renderAll();
  fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
});
```

...in order for it to render it as a video. I think that when the JSON is being load it is still treating it as an image file and not calling that said function. If there was a way to identify the type as video and not image then add this function to an if(type = video) statement then it could possibly work.

**But first I want to know that when you are loading through JSON if it actually places a blank image object on the canvas or not. OR if you actually fixed this problem let us know!**